# Getting error while using Firebase Analytics

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, mobile, cocoapods

Installing Firebase 10.22.0
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (10.22.0)

[!] Error installing FirebaseAnalytics
[!] /opt/homebrew/opt/curl/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/63/bpv_khfs2wj4rg4llvc2b_c40000gn/T/d20240319-11854-89oaob/file.tgz https://dl.google.com/firebase/ios/analytics/d9e6824c98c32455/FirebaseAnalytics-10.22.0.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.15.2 cocoapods-downloader/2.1'

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

I want to install Firebase Analytics using React Native App.

Comment: May be a transient network issue. Try again